# How can I take multiple users name and store in array using C#?

Tags: c#

I have tried many times but cannot figure it out, I simply want to take the users names and store it using an array here is my code so far, I have tried to take one user name and store it in the array.

Getting Exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
```

My Code:

```
using System;

namespace ProjectFour
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            string[] ClientNames = new string[i];
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
            string NameDude = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            ClientNames[i] = NameDude;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to declare variable i - that doesn't even compile.

Comment: You say `Visual Studio Code` in the post but `Visual Studio 2019` in the title, which is correct?

Comment: Are you wanting to gather *multiple* names, and put each in an array? Then you will need to use a loop and have some way for the user to say, "I'm done entering names." Please clarify your question as to the exact results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare variable i - and also, initial i or you can set the array size by putting value. Below the code where you can take one user name and store in index zero but if you want to take multiple user names then you have done by loop and storing user one by one in the array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int i = 1;
     string[] ClientNames = new string[i];
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
     string NameDude=Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
     ClientNames [0] = NameDude;
}
```

If you want to take multiple user name and store in the array, you may follow below code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      int arraySize = 5;
      string[] ClientNames = new string[arraySize];
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
      for(int i =0; i < arraySize; i++)
      {
            ClientNames[i] = Console.ReadLine();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mahi uddin that was very helpful.

Comment: Mahi Uddin is there a way I can reach you by email?

Answer (score 0):

1st, variable "i" never increases so you cannot store multiple usernames.
2nd you need loop so you can ask for multiple usernames, in the loop you will increase variable "i"